# metodo que debe agregar un nuevo objeto al array de la propiedad de un constructor

Tags: array, objeto, clase, constructor

Debo agregar un método que debe agregar amigos al array de grupoDeAmigos de la clase alumno. Añadí un objeto con las propiedades "nombre", "apellido" y "cohorte" (necesito que el value de cohorte sea el mismo que tiene asignado la instancia de "Alumno") en el array de grupoDeAmigos.

No se como darle a cohorte el mismo valor que tiene asignado la instancia de "Alumno"

```
// El constructor de la clase recibe nombre (string), apellido (string), cohorte (number), 
// grupoDeAmigos (array de objetos), notasCheckpoints (array de numbers).

class Alumno {
   constructor (nombre, apellido, cohorte, grupoDeAmigos, notasCheckpoints) {

       this.nombre = nombre,
       this.apellido = apellido,
       this.cohorte = cohorte,
       this.grupoDeAmigos = grupoDeAmigos,
       this.notasCheckpoints = notasCheckpoints

   };

// Este método debe agregar amigos al array de grupoDeAmigos del alumno.
// Añade un objeto con las propiedades "nombre", "apellido" y "cohorte" (siendo 
// el value de cohorte el mismo que tiene asignado la instancia de "Alumno") 
// en el array de grupoDeAmigos.
// No debe retornar nada.
//
// Tu código:

        addAmigos(nombre, apellido) {    
           this.grupoDeAmigos.push({
               nombre:  this.nombre,
               apellido: this.apellido,
               cohorte : Alumno.cohorte
```

Comment: y de que lenguaje estaríamos hablando?

Comment: parece ser java pero es mejor que lo diga

Comment: disculpen la demora, es lenguaje java script. en si lo que no se es como darle a cohorte en el metodo addAmigos el mismo valor que tiene cohorte en la clase alumno